# iPhone device testing issue with xcode upgrade

Tags: iphone, xcode, device

My iPhone device has become ineligible device after upgrading Xcode to 6.3.
 I was able to see my app on my iPhone device before. After upgrade it is shown under ineligible device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off the device and turn it on again before testing app on your device.

Comment: I found another solution. In Xcode go to Product > Destination to select your device. Even though it says your device is ineligible, it will still allow you to select it. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your device to iOS 8.3 according to Xcode 6.3.

Comment: You sure ? I had the exact same issues 2 days ago. My answer fixed it.  In addition be sure your provisionning si valid.

Comment: Yes I am am sure. Do I need to do anything with the provisioning? I removed x-code and reinstalled it. After re-installation so i need to do anything for provisioning file?

Comment: Check that all is right with them and re-add it to your new Xcode installation

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the Deployment Target. Change the deployment Target